# Interpretation of a multi-thread example from cppreference in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17

I have found a program in [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t):

```
std::atomic<int> x{0};
int a[] = {1,2};
std::for_each(std::execution::par, std::begin(a), std::end(a), [&](int) {
    x.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    while (x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1) { } // Error: assumes execution order
});
```

What does the word "Error: assumes execution order" mean, i.e. what is the error of this program? It seems that the program aims to show a deadlock, but I cannot see that.

I know the title is unclear, but I really don't know how to describe the problem since I cannot find any mistake in the program. Sorry about that.

Comment: This is C++17 question? If so, please add the tag.

Comment: @hyde OK. Execution policy is new in C++17, but I think this is just a multi-thread problem, which has little to do with the new feature.

Comment: The code assumes that two lambda calls will execute in parallel. But `std::execution::par` only says that they *may* execute in parallel. If they aren't - if they end up being called on the same thread in sequence after all - then the program will enter an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is from [the draft (e.g. N4606 [algorithms.parallel.exec]/3)](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.parallel.exec#3) :

> [ Example:

```
std::atomic<int> x{0};
int a[] = {1,2};
std::for_each(std::execution::par, std::begin(a), std::end(a), [&](int) {
  x.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
  // spin wait for another iteration to change the value of x
  while (x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1) { } // incorrect: assumes execution order
});
```

> The above example depends on the order of execution of the iterations, and will not terminate if both iterations are executed sequentially on the same thread of execution.  — end example ]